# Sql delete returns deleted 0 rows

Tags: php, pdo

```
    ...
    $count = $conn->exec("
        DELETE FROM date_practice 
        WHERE  date between '.$dateBefor.' AND '.$dateAfter.' 
    ");

    print("Deleted $count rows.\n"); 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . '<br />' . $e->getMessage();
} 
$conn = NULL; 
?>
```

It prints Deleted 0 rows.

Comment: Should rows be deleted? Are you sure your SQL is correct? Also, you haven't given a complete block of code.

Comment: What are the values of $dateBefor and $dateAfter?  Can you verify that there are some rows you expect to delete (and what are their dates)?  Can you verify that they didn't get deleted, and the problem isn't just a reporting error?

Comment: Silly question... but is there any chance that you should be using $dateBefore instead of $dateBefor?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your `.`s (concatenation operators) are inside your double-quotes, so they're considered part of they string. The literal query this sends will look like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM date_practice WHERE date between '.2011-01-01.' and '.2011-12-31.'
```

Try this:

```
$count = $conn->exec(
  "DELETE FROM date_practice " .
  "  WHERE date BETWEEN '$dateBefor' AND '$dateAfter'"
);
```

Better yet, since you're already using PDO use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), which will worry about variable interpolation for you and protect you against SQL injection attacks:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(
  'DELETE FROM date_practice ' .
  '  WHERE date BETWEEN :before AND :after'
);

$stmt->bindParam(':before', $dateBefor);
$stmt->bindParam(':after',  $dateAfter);

$stmt->execute();

echo 'Deleted ', $stmt->rowCount(), ' rows.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this

```
$count = $conn->exec("DELETE FROM date_practice WHERE  date between '$dateBefor' and '$dateAfter' ");
```

Perhaps without `''` around dates. We don't know what format you used and what your databasse accepts.